# Click a listView, open dialog for password, and then check the clicked item

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I created a listView (CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE). By clicking on a list item a dialog window opens that asks for a password. I don't want the item to get checked by clicking on it, but by confirming the password. what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ListView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean value) method.
Probably by using getListView().setItemChecked(int, boolean) from the activity/fragment which holds the listView.

I guess the only thing to do then is getting the info whether the password was accepted back to the listView activity/fragment. There are quite some methods to do that, which are explained quite some times on the internet.